# Is this notification that keeps coming up on my phone a virus?

Tags: notifications, malware

This notification keeps coming up, and i'm not sure if it's real or a virus, or how to stop it coming up.
It says 'Android system warning! Google has found serious bugs in your Battery Module!Click on [OK] to view details.'

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Any help appreciated, thanks.
Lauren.

Comment: I agree with Erman and kasperd's answers. As an additional resource, it might be a case of [cross-site scripting](http://www.wikipedia.com/en/Cross-site_scripting), when an honest website is injected by malicious JavaScript hosted on other site, as seen on the screenshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not a virus. The notification is triggered by advertisements on the webpage.

Just don't click "OK" and ignore it.

Comment: Careful. What you see there definitely points to malware. No website scans your "battery module" (whatever that should be) and reports *Google* has found serious bugs in it. Google doesn't work that way. I'd rather go with [TimoS' attempt](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/91657/16575) on locating and eliminating the source. If that doesn't work out, check whether that happens on specific pages only and avoid those (at least for a while, as they might be infected). // Edit: Better make the "don't" bold and italics – I've just seen that after writing my comment :)

Comment: @Izzy: the website aren't doing any scanning, they would most likely still show that you have issue in your battery, even when you don't actually have a battery. It's a Trojan, your system is likely not infected (yet), the only way your system would be in danger is if you're stupid enough  to invite the horse in and install whatever "fix" the dialog box claim would've solved a nonexistent problem. Best action is to avoid the site that triggers them.

Comment: @Izzy - this definitely is not a virus or malware. Notice that it says "The page at http://---- says" -- this is a traditional `window.alert()` box, and that is the title that comes with it.

Comment: @Lie Ryan + Seiyra + lzzy: You are right. BUT: Cause of it's annoying you should find the application which opens this webpage/runs this js and uninstall/deactivate it. Just 'Click OK and relax' is not an option.

Comment: @TimoS: right, but you won't be finding the offending application by going through your installed application list, since it's the browser doing this rather than a native application. The OP has 16 pages open, and some of it probably are one he has been using regularly. The source of the alert is most likely a web page that he'd just recently opened. There's nothing to worry  because the system is not compromised; as long as he can avoid the page that triggers the message, there is nothing to freak out about.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: But it might be an app which opens this webpage.

Comment: No, it's definitely not a *virus* (there are none for Android) :) Lie's explanation is showing the most likely culprit (I forgot about `window.alert()`). So stick to the second half of my last comment (avoiding the site causing this until they've fixed it). You never know what happens when you confirm the request. Maybe they just want to "shock you" – but maybe they want to install some malware in the next step.

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing looks like a javascript alert.

As long as you don't believe the lies some websites will be feeding you, the only danger a javascript alert introduces is the possibility that a site may keep opening so many javascript alerts, that you won't be able to leave the site before another alert pops up. But a decent browser can stop that for you.

In this particular case I guess it is a case of an advertiser lying to you in order to convince you to buy a product which you don't need.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an App which opens that dialog (over a webpage...).

Try to boot into safe mode:

Press and hold the power button until the power menu appears.

Hold down 'Reboot'. (On phones which do not have the option to reboot press and hold 'Power off')

Then your phone will reboot into safe mode. That means all your apps are deactivated for this session. IF you won't get any of these weird dialogs there THEN restart your phone (to get all your apps back) and deactivate/uninstall your apps step by step.

You can also try AdAway, which has an inbuilt AdWare Scanner. (https://f-droid.org/repo/org.adaway_51.apk)

Comment: I didn't knew adaway has an adware scanner.

Comment: Sure it's right in the menu. http://imgur.com/FUQqFeA

Comment: I agree with this approach. Though it might be an infected website displaying an "advertisement", the phrasing clearly points to malware – and the look of it to an app displaying a dialog. So follow this first – and if it doesn't work out, check whether the message only appears on specific websites (which might be infected); if so, better avoid them at least for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Not a virus, but a simply advertising popup which leads at website to avoid. Block the url from your browser!

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot Pro displays these annoying, persistent ads with "smart application management" notifications.   If that's not it then look for other apps that you recently installed or updated in Google Play with WiFi access. Disable notifications on the suspected app to see if it is the source of the ads,  then uninstall it if disabling removes the ads.  I had to disable it as a device administrator to uninstall screenshot pro.