# Is my Android affected by malware?

Tags: antivirus

Occassionally when I click on a link in Google Now for one of the cards for something I've searched for (in this case, it was SmartPhones), it'll open up the site and then immediately open up a popup.

For example, I went to this site (http://www.knowyourmobile.com/android/htc-one-m8/22962/htc-one-m8-and-htc-one-m7-android-lollipop-update-confirmed) and it immediately opened up this site (http://mostawesomeoffers.com/mobile/en/iPhone/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsofcotrk.com%2Fmt%2Fw284y284d4s233r244r2r234%2F%26subid1%3D14121906_04_219_5493b18c27b16cf2)

I've opened up the site on my computer but it doesn't open up this popup. It's only when I click on the link from Google Now.

So is my mobile infected with a virus or is this just part of the site? KnowYourMobile seems to be a pretty popular site and not the type of site that would put in these types of ad.

It seems weird that I would get a virus on it but I only install apps from the google play store (and not a lot either) and my phone isn't rooted or unlocked or whatever.

If it is a virus, how do I get rid of it and how could it have infected my mobile (eg. browsing the net?)

Comment: It is a just a pop-up (ad) and you can keep the phone away from ads using an app called AdAway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this notification that keeps coming up on my phone a virus?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91656/is-this-notification-that-keeps-coming-up-on-my-phone-a-virus), though not dialog, but same approach.

Comment: Well, that gives me a feel that you have installed some app over to your android device that's pushing ads over your device better option will be heading over to the application manager and remove the app you doubt about or you can also install ad blocker application available outside the PlayStore! :)

Comment: I recommend actually removing the offending application. I am 100% against any kind of ad blocking software. The developers are (usually) offering the app for free because of the advertisements. If you block them, you are taking from their revenue. If you don't like the ads, there is usually an ad free version that you pay for. Ad blockers are a form of piracy, which is why they are not allowed on the Google Play Store.

Comment: @peter - which application is the offending application though? As far as i know all the apps i have gave good ratings on Google play and wouldn't be the type to hijack my browser or Google now app

Comment: You can try installing [AirPush Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en) it will let you know which application is pushing ads over your device ! See if this helps !