# How do I get rid of random redirections

Tags: malware

When browsing, I sometimes get random redirections to websites claiming my device has viruses, and that I need to click a link to get rid of those. They also make my phone vibrate, and the back button gets me nowhere, I am stuck to the page.

Somes sites I get redirected to include :

- paly.google.com.store.apps.seebestpossible.com/findvirusfrcdnew
- androidmarketstore.co/of/dus.php
- yeah.youmadethedeal.com/mobiledirect/?aid=62079&uid=219
- ...

So my questions are :

- What's causing this ?
- How do I make it stop ?
- What can I do to prevent this from happening again ?

Additional info :

- I am using Chrome
- The phone is rooted
- Using android 5.0.2

Comment: Clear the data and cache of chrome and see if that helps. I've had this issue before and that's all it took.

Comment: 1) Because that's status-by-design.  The websites on which you're getting redirected want you to be redirected. Those links are attempt of phishing and comes into action mostly through ads on those websites. Those ads are primarily targeted on mobile browsers. 2) Use an ad blocker and see what happens. 3) Keep the ad blocker updated. I don't browse much using mobile so other users may have better suggestions.

Comment: 1) JavaScript, or any script embedded on the site. 2) Turning of JavaScript may prevent some of redirection, though many clean websites will also probably break. 3) see --> 2. Also, related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93105/preventing-browser-redirects-on-android-and-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this headache for long time. But,  then I discovered this app by [Adblock](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-about). This works on rooted android phone. And blocks all the ads displayed by various applications on your phone.

Be sure to download the adblock app,  not the adblock browser. And yes,  they have a browser for web surfing without ads, also works without rooting the device.